# Is it possible to have a default class in multi class classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

In the general text classification problem, training a machine learning model to detect if a text belongs to one of N number of classes always yields a value in N. Even if the text that was passed to the model is very far outside any of the N classes (like say you trained it on categories for movie genres, but someone passed a recipe to the classifier), it will always choose one of N as the output even though the text passed to it doesn't belong to any of the classes.

Is there a method to have an additional class for 'unknown' so that if the model output is one of the N types but matches it with very low probability then assign it to the default or unknown class?

**EDIT:** we are using LinearSVC from sci kit learn

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the model but this would be a post-processing move.

E.g. in a recent problem I trained a random forest classifier and then classified any data point where the probability of the likeliest class was less than 50% as unknown.

Answer (score 1):

just use `predict_proba` and in the end if *p* is lower than some threshold (for 10 classes all p will be ~.1 and best could have 0.2 so if it's to low for you) you will just change predition from "class1" to "unknown", it's impossible to add it to model

Comment: I was getting this when I tried `AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'` so I think the model was trained with `probability=False` in which case I was reading I could use `decision_function` instead to get the confidence for each class?

Comment: @sjs to `decision_function` output you should apply `scipy.special.softmax` to get probabilities for each class, because you will just get distance from decision boundary (with sign)